# Extract value from the array of objects

Tags: javascript, filter, foreach

I have an array of objects in a variable and I have id of the provider in a different variable. How do I get the name of the provider based on the id. how do I get the name based on the id. when I compare the id variable with with variable containing the array of objects.

Array of objects:

```
0: Object { id: "620d77165bd6857e3bdfed46", name: "provider 2", type: "TMS" }

1: Object { id: "620d771a5bd6857e3bdfed49", name: "provider 3", type: "Other" }

2: Object { id: "620d77205bd6857e3bdfed4c", name: "provider 4", type: "Load Board" }

3: Object { id: "62220e49c547d431a94c2aa8", name: "provider 5", type: "TMS" }

4: Object { id: "62221b86c547d431a94c2aba", name: "provider 6", type: "Load Board" }

5: Object { id: "6226887428359eb63456901a", name: "provider 1", type: "Load Board" }

6: Object { id: "62309b7d75a9fe3632ed9649", name: "asd", type: "TMS" }

7: Object { id: "62309b8375a9fe3632ed964f", name: "asdasdas", type: "Load Board" }

8: Object { id: "6230de7eb8432ab865c77a04", name: "asd provider 2", type: "Load Board" }

9: Object { id: "6230e05fb8432ab865c77a09", name: "adad", type: "Load Board" }

10: Object { id: "6230e091b8432ab865c77a10", name: "adada123123", type: "Load Board" }

11: Object { id: "6230e0e8b8432ab865c77a19", name: "asdasdasdadasdasda", type: "Load Board" }

12: Object { id: "6230e22db8432ab865c77a20", name: "adasd", type: "Load Board" }

13: Object { id: "6230e239b8432ab865c77a29", name: "adasd12312313123", type: "TMS" }

14: Object { id: "623366f8fc1ac7ff6f7bbd17", name: "asasasaaaaaaaaaaaa1111111111", type: "Load Board" }

15: Object { id: "6233670dfc1ac7ff6f7bbd25", name: "asasasaa1212111111", type: "Select a Type" }

16: Object { id: "62337769dac5619a6c6f56f9", name: "simpleProovider", type: "newTMS" }

17: Object { id: "6241a25e5bc31aec9152932f", name: "Uber Frieght", type: "Load Board" }
```

What i have tried so far.

```
let result = providerList.map(({ id }) => name);
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` function.

```
const result = providerList.find((x) => x.id === yourId);
const name = result? result.name : null;
```

Or you can get it with `lodash` library.

```
const name = _.get(_.find(providerList, {id: yourId}), 'name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)) to search your array of objects for a specific value.

```js
const result = providerList.find((e) => e.id === "id_to_look_for");
```

Useful documentation links

- [Array.prototype.find on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- [Array.prototype.map on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a filter for this

```
const result = providerList.filter((x) => x.id === yourId);
```

or you can even use find , the difference between find and filter is that filter can be used to find multiple values that satisfies the condition  `e.id === yourId`
while find can be used to find unique value

```
const result = providerList.find((x) => x.id === yourId);
```